# Nodejs app can't connect to local MySQL on FreeBSD 8.2-STABLE

Tags: mysql, node.js, freebsd

guys.

I've installed MySQL module for node.js using `npm install mysql` and bumped into connection error.

Here's my js code.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'userpassword',
  database : 'node'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ' + fields);
});

connection.end();
```

Here's the output I get:

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'node'@'146.66.*.*' (using password: YES)
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:101:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:270:23)
at Parser.write (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:82:28)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:108:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/www/apache22/data/node/local_db.js:9:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

The thing is that instead of connecting to MySQL via `localhost` (as I specified in connection options) it goes through `externalIPaddress` (for no obvious reason) and firewall drops connection in accordance with it's rules.

I've searched for solutions in other topics, but either error output or suitable solutions differ a lot.

I've also tried popular solutions for related problems from other questions and this is the list of options, that didn't work for me:
1. Flushing MySQL privileges table after new user creation and granting necessary privileges.
2. Modifying `/etc/hosts` to get proper answer from `nslookup localhost` and `nslookup localhost.`
3. Manually pointing path to MySQL socket also hasn't change anything.
4. I do not use `host` and `server` options at the same time.
5. I've tried 3306 port specifying.

After all, I still get the same error.

Thank's for your help in advance.

Comment: Tried using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @arved Yes, sure. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

By default `mysql` binds and listens to the "everything" address at `0.0.0.0`.  Perhaps your `node` and your `node.js` module are doing the same thing. This would make requests and responses come over your external interface and trigger your firewall.

From your output I assume `node` and MySQL are on the same machine and that you are using Apache as a reverse proxy. If this is the case only `httpd` should be listening to ports on external addresses: `node`, `mysql`, etc. should be talking to each other over local interfaces or via sockets.

Check your configuration and make sure `node` and `mysql-server` are binding/listening to ports on the `lo` interface, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. This could resolve your problem.

HTH, G'Cito